# Getting error "Injection of autowired dependencies failed;" when adding another entity class to annotedClasses list in spring

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, hibernate

Please help me I am totally stuck at one thing.

In my program everything was running fine when I was working with only one entity class called Person but when i have added one more entity class called Specimen it throws me exception like `"hibernate exception unknown entity Specimen"` after searching on google I have added "Specimen" class in  annottedClasses list but after adding it throwing me exception

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.swapnil.service.RegisterService

Below is my code:

Home controller:

```
package com.swapnil.controller;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.omg.CORBA.portable.ApplicationException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.swapnil.models.Person;
import com.swapnil.models.User;
import com.swapnil.service.RegisterService;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private RegisterService registerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = { RequestMethod.GET,
            RequestMethod.POST })
    public String welcomePage(ModelMap map) {
        System.out.println("*****");
        map.addAttribute("message", "Welcome to Spring mvc");
        return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayregistrationPage(Model map) {
        User userObj = new User();
        map.addAttribute("user", userObj);
        return "register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doRegistration(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user,
            BindingResult result, Model model) {
        int id = 0;
        System.out.println(user);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "register";
        } else {
            if (!registerService.checkUser(user)) {
                try {
                    id = registerService.addUser(user);
                } catch (ApplicationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        model.addAttribute("userid", id);

        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/shortregister", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    public String shortregister(Model map) {

        Person personObj = new Person();
        map.addAttribute("person", personObj);
        return "shortReg";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/shortregister", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public String shortregisterDo(Model map,
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("person") Person person, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            // throw new CustomGenericException("407",
            // "something is missing required for registration");
            return "shortReg";
        } else {
            registerService.addPerson(person);
            return "welcome";
        }

    }

}
```

personDAO:-

```
package com.swapnil.dao;
import java.util.List;
import com.swapnil.models.Person;
import com.swapnil.models.Specimen;

    public interface PersonDAO {

        public void save(Person p);

        public List<Person> list();

        public int addSpecimen(Specimen specimen);
    }
```

personDAOImpl--

```
package com.swapnil.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.swapnil.models.Person;
import com.swapnil.models.Specimen;

@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {

    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected DataSource ds;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public DataSource getDs() {
        return ds;
    }

    public void setDs(DataSource ds) {
        this.ds = ds;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(Person p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("session factipwpf " + sessionFactory);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        System.out.println("sesstion " + session);
        // System.out.println("connection   "+session.connection());
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println(p);
        // System.out.println("last saved user "+session.save(p));
        // session.persist(p);
        // System.out.println("persist id "+session.getIdentifier(p));
        SQLQuery query = session
                .createSQLQuery("insert into person(id,name,country) values(:id,:name,:country)");
        query.setParameter("id", p.getId());
        query.setParameter("name", p.getName());
        query.setParameter("country", p.getCountry());
        query.executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> list() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from person");
        List<Person> plist = query.list();
        return plist;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public int addSpecimen(Specimen specimen) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        int id = (Integer) session.save(specimen);
        tx.commit();
        return id;
    }

}
```

RegisterService--

```
package com.swapnil.service;

import com.swapnil.models.Person;
import com.swapnil.models.Specimen;
import com.swapnil.models.User;

public interface RegisterService {

    public Boolean checkUser(User user);

    public int addUser(User user);

    public int addPerson(Person person);

    public int addspecimen(Specimen specimen);

}
```

RegisterServiceImpl--

```
package com.swapnil.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.swapnil.dao.PersonDAO;
import com.swapnil.models.Person;
import com.swapnil.models.Specimen;
import com.swapnil.models.User;

@Service
public class RegisterServiceImpl implements RegisterService {

    @Autowired
    PersonDAO personDAO;

    @Override
    public Boolean checkUser(User user) {
        boolean userPresentFlag = false;
        if (null != user) {
            if (user.getFname().equalsIgnoreCase("swapnil")) {
                userPresentFlag = true;
            }
        }
        return userPresentFlag;
    }

    @Override
    public int addUser(User user) {
        int id;
        if (null == user) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        } else {
            id = user.getUserid();
        }
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public int addPerson(Person person) {
        personDAO.save(person);
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int addspecimen(Specimen specimen) {
        return personDAO.addSpecimen(specimen);

    }

}
```

below is the my configuration file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">


   <context:component-scan base-package="com.swapnil.controller"/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.swapnil.service"/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.swapnil.dao"/>

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
        <property name="username" value="swapnil" />
        <property name="password" value="swapnil" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="hibernate3AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.swapnil.models.Person</value>
                <value>com.swapnil.models.Specimen</value>             
            </list>
        </property>
       <!-- <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.swapnil.models" ></property> --> 
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">SWAPNIL</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>
    <bean id="personDAO" class="com.swapnil.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate3AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

every thing was fine before adding  com.swapnil.models.Specimen in configuration file please help me.
below is the snap of Specimen class

Specimen---

```
package com.swapnil.models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "SPECIMEN_DETAILS")
public class Specimen {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SPECIMEN_DETAILS_SEQ")
    private int id;

    @Size(min = 4, max = 8)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 1)
    private int specimenid;

    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 1)
    private int projectid;

    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 1)
    private int technologyid;

    @Size(min = 4)
    private String description;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public int getSpecimenid() {
        return specimenid;
    }

    public void setSpecimenid(int specimenid) {
        this.specimenid = specimenid;
    }

    public int getProjectid() {
        return projectid;
    }

    public void setProjectid(int projectid) {
        this.projectid = projectid;
    }

    public int getTechnologyid() {
        return technologyid;
    }

    public void setTechnologyid(int technologyid) {
        this.technologyid = technologyid;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Specimen [id=" + id + ", username=" + username
                + ", specimenid=" + specimenid + ", projectid=" + projectid
                + ", technologyid=" + technologyid + ", description="
                + description + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: please post the COMPLETE stacktrace, (the real reason is somewhere in the exception causes)

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the  `@Service` like this:

```
    @Service("registerService")
    public class RegisterServiceImpl implements RegisterService {
```